# Problem saving (C-x C-s) files on a NFS drive with emacs 24/25

Tags: files, linux, saving

Starting with Emacs 24 (using various different versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint), if I open a file on an NFS drive, modify it and attempt to save it <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>, I get the message of: `Saving <filename>...`, but the file does not save, and is still marked as having been changed.

If I save the file with a <kbd>C-x C-w</kbd>, the file will save, and all subsequent <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> attempts for that file will succeed until the buffer is killed.

This problem does not exist on the same machine/file system if I use Emacs 23.

Comment: If you don't get help here for this I'd suggest filing an Emacs bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) or at least asking at `help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`.

Comment: What options is the NFS filesystem mounted with? What OS does the NFS server run and how is it configured (if you don't know, ask your system administrator)?

Comment: The system used autofs, and the mount options for my system are:

`rw,nosuid,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountvers=3,mountport=20048,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none`

I believe the server is a Centos 6 system. I am trying to find out from the sysadmin what the options for that machine are.

Comment: FWIW, it seems to be OK on emacs-26. client is fedora-29, server is fedora-24, `nfsstat -m` shows nothing, `/etc/exports` options are `rw,no_root_squash,sync`

Comment: I can't think of any specific reason why you're seeing this, but as for why it works with `C-x C-w` and subsequent `C-x C-s`, it seems likely that it's because the initial `C-x C-s` obeys  `bakup-by-copying` (and other variables `backup-by-copying-*`).